# ¿Se pueden colocar mas de un id en un solo input type text?

Tags: javascript, html

mi pregunta es si se pueden colocar mas de un id en un input porque tengo una funcion en *javacript* que la mando a llamar en el id de un input type text pero en ese input tambien tengo que tener el id con la variable de mi base de datos. donde se insertaran los datos.

este es el codigo del input:

```
<td>
  <h5>Avance 1:</h5>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="CONTRATO" id="total" size="5" value="<%= rs.getString(5) %>" disabled="0">
</td>
```

el nombre de mi funcion Javascript es `total` y la variable de mi base de datos se llama `contrato`

¿Cómo le podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es: NO. Ahora bien si quieres un poco mas de ayuda, para una solución seria bueno poder replantear tu duda y copiar la funcion llamada total

Comment: No entiendo cómo esta pregunta tiene 5 respuestas y yo no logro todavía entender qué necesita hacer el usuario. No creo que le baste saber que NO se pueden poner dos id.

Comment: @amenadiel: Sería mejor que dejaras comentarios como ese en las respuestas que te parecen poco claras o incompletas, aunque cabe mencionar que es válido publicar respuestas parciales.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo con un div que tiene 2 id, el la primera llamada con el primer id funciona, en cambio cuando se llama al segundo div existe un error!!!
}

**conclusion: no puede existir 2 id en un elemento.**

```js
var texto=document.getElementById("uno").innerHTML;
console.log(texto);

var texto=document.getElementById("primero").innerHTML;
console.log(texto);
```

```html
<div id="uno" id="primero"> 1</div>
```

Comment: El ID siempre debe ser único en cada elemento.

Comment: Creo que tambien puedes exponer cuando el `id` se hace de esta manera `id="total conclucion"`, observa que hay 2 id e igual marca error :D

Answer (score 6):

Respondiendo a la pregunta, **NO** puedes colocar más de un id a un elemento y además este id tiene que ser único en todo el documento.

Una solución para asignar más datos en el elemento es utilizar el atributo `data`. Por ejemplo puedes crear inputs así:

```
<input id="input_1" data-type="total" data-name="contract" type="text" size="5" value="1" disabled="0">
```

Y con Javascript obtendrías los valores de la siguiente manera:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('input_1');

myInput.dataset.type // "total"
myInput.dataset.name // "contract"
```

Comment: al atributo data-type o data-name sus valores se pueden repetir por ejemplo    
  <input id="obj1" data-type="total" data-name="contract" type="text">     
  <input id="obj2" data-type="total" data-name="contract" type="text">

Answer (score 3):

Por definición una función,objeto,clase,etc. debe de poseer un Nombre único el cual le sirve de Identificador para futuras referencias y llamadas que se deseen hacer según el caso.

Lo que si se puede hacer (mas no lo recomiendo) es utilizar un numerador para el identificador por ejemplo:

```
string variable1;
string variable2;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es tener dos variables con el mismo id solo agregamos un numerador, en la practica esto no es recomendable por que puede ocasionar malentendidos después y posibles bugs.

Espero te sirva la aclaración, saludos.

P.D.Puedes leer [este](http://claseinfo.blogia.com/temas/identificadores/) articulo sobre Identificadores si te interesa.

Comment: Es mejor decir que se se puede repetir la parte inicial, usar prefijos, u otra forma, pero no que es el mismo id pues al agregar un número los has vuelto diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Como ya te comentaron definitivamente no puedes tener un mismo ID para diferentes elementos es un identificador unico e irrepetible, lo que bien podrias hacer es poner otro input y lo ocultas y ahi mandas el ID que necesitas y listo.

Answer (score 3):

Veo que te comentaron todos que NO puedes poner dos id eso es correcto pero puedes crearte un nuevo atributo `objectid` por ejemplo y jugar con eso

```
<input type="text" name="CONTRATO" id="total" objectid="fb13a2ac-bd10-db11-b07d-000fea72363c" size="5" value="<%= rs.getString(5) %>" disabled="0">
```

Comment: En este sitio las respuestas deberían ser "autocontenidas", por lo cual es válido repetir algo que se ha dicho en otra respuesta (si es algo original recuerda dar la atribución correspondiente) para dar contexto a la aportación que realizas.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puedes usar es la propiedad `name`.

```
<input id="usandoId" name="usandoName" type="text" />
```

Comment: Si bien ofrece una alternativa, falta explicar el motivo por el cual se requiere.