# ¿Es posible poner dos id dentro de un div? tengo que usar HTML y CSS

Tags: css, html5

Estoy haciendo una recreación de una página web y quiero añadir dos id dentro de un div.Necesito hacerlo para crear un tipo de footer en concreto pero no lo consigo,ayuda por favor.

Comment: Posible respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51066/se-pueden-colocar-mas-de-un-id-en-un-solo-input-type-text

Comment: No puedes poner dos id a un solo elemento, pero podrías tener dos elementos anidados cada uno con su id. Me gustaría ver que quieres hacer exactamente. A lo mejor hay una solución alternativa. ¿Por favor, puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir el código para el footer explicando que es lo que quieres conseguir?

Answer (score 3):

Para tener un HTML válido debería tener solo un ID por cada elemento html. Si necesitas asignarle varios atributos por qué en lugar de ID no usas clases? Sí puedes poner todas las clases que necesites dentro de un div, así:

```
<div class="clase1 clase2 clase3 clase4 clase5" id="id1"></div>
```